# Decrypting a file with GNU PGP inside a container: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: linux, docker, gpg

I'm trying to decrypt a file with a GPG private key I was given and a passphrase. We are using a Docker container running ubuntu 18.04 LTS for our decryption process. The docker container runs a shell script running gpg.

I started with testing on a local machine. This works on OSX and a remote Ubuntu server:

```
gpg --batch --import key
gpg --batch --output decrypted.txt --passphrase "passphrase" --decrypt encrypted.txt
```

However, when I try to import the key inside the docker container, I get the error `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found` I also tried using  `--no-default-keyring --keyring trustedkeys.gpg` to create a new keyring.

Any help is appreciated.